# I'm trying to retrieve files from an ubuntu server from a win 7 machine with Paramiko module

Tags: python, windows, paramiko

I'm getting a 'Permission denied' error when I set a local path name of my windows file system with the get method (Paramiko). Has anyone encountered this or know how to resolve it? I am logged in as the administrator. Below is the code and traceback error. Thanks!

Code:

```
 import paramiko
 import sys
 import os





 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect('10.5.48.72', username='root', password='******')


 apath = '/var/log'
 apattern = '"*.log"'
 rawcommand = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
 command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
 filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
```

This is the correct code. It searches an Ubuntu server at the root for all log and text files, and retrieves the files and saves them to a local directory (c:\Extracted):

```
sim_ip = raw_input('Host: ')
pattern = r"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"

if re.match(pattern, sim_ip):

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(sim_ip, username='root', password='*****')
apath = '/'
apattern = '"*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' 
rawcommand = 'find {path} -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' #{pattern}
command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
ftp = ssh.open_sftp() 
for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    print(filename)
    ftp.get(afile, 'c:\\Extracted\\' + filename)  #'./'+filename)

ftp.close()
ssh.close()

else:
    print "You entered an invalid IP Address!!!"
```

Comment: Please disregard!!! I figured it out ... thanks!

Comment: Could you please at least post what your problem was as an answer instead of editing the question to say "nevermind"? Even if the answer was just that you made a stupid mistake, other people may have the same symptoms in the future.

Comment: @Mu Mind Yes ... sorry about that.

Comment: @user706808 Please add your fixed code as an answer and mark it as "answered" :)